# Cannot connect content server docbase in windows2008(64bit) from windows7(32bit)

Tags: documentum, dfc

Error occurred when I connect docbase in windows2008(64bit) from windows7(32bit) using DFC. (the content server version is Developer_Edition_6.6_windows_sql).

> DfServiceException:: THREAD: main; MSG:
>   [DFC_SESSION_DOCBASE_UNREACHABLE] Docbase "documentum" is unreachable;
>   ERRORCODE: ff; NEXT: null
>       at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection.establishNewRpcClient(DocbaseConnection.java:259)
>       at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection.open(DocbaseConnection.java:122)
>       at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection.(DocbaseConnection.java:96)
>       at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection.(DocbaseConnection.java:60)
>       at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnectionFactory.newDocbaseConnection(DocbaseConnectionFactory.java:26)
>       at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnectionManager.getDocbaseConnection(DocbaseConnectionManager.java:74)
>       at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.SessionFactory.newSession(SessionFactory.java:29)
>       at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.PrincipalAwareSessionFactory.newSession(PrincipalAwareSessionFactory.java:35)
>       at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.PooledSessionFactory.newSession(PooledSessionFactory.java:47)
>       at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.SessionManager.getSessionFromFactory(SessionManager.java:111)
>       at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.SessionManager.newSession(SessionManager.java:64)
>       at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.SessionManager.getSession(SessionManager.java:168)
>       at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.classmgmt.ModuleManager.connect(ModuleManager.java:356)
>       at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.classmgmt.ModuleManager.init(ModuleManager.java:311)
>       at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.classmgmt.ModuleManager.getInstance(ModuleManager.java:36)
>       at com.documentum.fc.client.security.impl.DfcIdentityPublisher.(DfcIdentityPublisher.java:44)
>       at com.documentum.fc.client.security.internal.RegistrationMgr.register(RegistrationMgr.java:34)
>       at com.documentum.fc.impl.RuntimeContext.(RuntimeContext.java:191)
>       at com.documentum.fc.client.DfClient.(DfClient.java:721)
>       at com.documentum.com.DfClientX.getLocalClient(DfClientX.java:43)

But if I use the same DFC code on windows XP, it work fine...

Also, I can connect another docbase in windowsXP from this windows7(32bit) using same DFC code.

I have shutdown all firewall in these machines. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure, this is a networking problem.

First, try to find out whether you can connect to your docbroker host / port. If that fails, you know where to start. Also doublecheck your dfc.properties and your firewall settings (again) on these settings and also the global repository configuration.

Maybe, this could also have something to do with your IPv6? I heard about issues with IPv6 and also encountered some myself (but these were on Linux).

Another (tiny) idea: When you access DA / Webtop from your Windows 7 Machine, do you also face the same problem? Also, you could try to setup a local Webserver and deploy DA / Webtop there. This could give you more information and indicate, whether this problem is related to your DFC-code or not.

Maybe also restart all your service (Docbase, DocBroker, Method Server).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks max, I also think this is networking problem. But I have disabled all firewall as well as IPV6, the docbase & DFC code work fine for other machine whose OS is not win7..... Thanks for your commnet again.

Comment: Have you tried to connect to the DocBroker via telnet (on the DocBroker's port)?

Comment: yeah, the telnet is ok....and I have install xp instead of win7...it work fine now..,it is very strange... thanks max.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, IPV6 affects!
IPV6 has to be ALIVE under Windows domain member PC.
(Workgroup member is not affected)
and x:\Documentum\Cache folder has to be writable.